# How to send multiple magnet links to a separate headless Linux machine?

Tags: linux, headless, magnet-links, w3m

With torrents, we could use w3m (Linux) to pass multiple torrent files to a separate machine running rtorrent.  This doesn't work with magnet links.  We can pass magnet links from Firefox to Azureus with no problem, but the sending machine and the machine actually doing the processing do not use X.

Has anyone already accomplished this task?  We've spent days on the problem so far, with little to show for it.

Comment: Is the question about multiple magnet links, or just getting rtorrent to process a magnet link?  How is the sending machine aquiring the magnet link in the first place - via w3m still?

Comment: (1) I tried to answer your question, but it didn't seem to take.  (2) This solution has nothing to do with utorrent, I just offer it for closure, and the possible help to others -- The problem we faced lies in the instability of older versions of rtorrent and libtorrent. rtorrent 0.8.9 and libtorrent 0.12.9 are stable and will correctly load magnet links if the magnet link is wrapped as given by the script provided by rtorrent.

As far as I know rtorrent is the only client that can handle magnet links dropped in to the client as easily as torrents.

Comment: Sure - but now I am less clear on what your question is.  You appear to be saying that you are able to pass magnet links through to rtorrent, using the wrapper script in traq, so what part is missing?

Answer (score 1):

One of the better clients I have encountered is Transmission.

It supports magnet links, NAT traversal and all kind of operations on files that I've grown accustomed to from uTorrent 2.x. That includes selecting/disabling certain files from a torrent and moving files to another download location or selecting a location when a torrent is loaded.

To use Transmission you will have to run the daemon which is the background "downloader" and access it with a GUI or CLI client.

Adding a magnet when the transmission daemon is running on a given port is a simple matter of:

```
transmission-remote lanbox:9191 --add magnet:?xt=urn:btih:78a93b68819100e4 (...)
```

Where lanbox is a host alias and 9191 is the listening port of the transmission daemon.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and decided to have a look at it today.

Here is [how to handle magnet URIs with w3m](http://boeglin.org/blog/index.php?entry=entry120314-214917).

Comment: please expand your answer, link only answers tend to die from link-rot. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Follow the instructions on [Magnet URIs in rTorrent](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/MagnetUri), if you want to send the resulting torrent files to a remote machine, just use sshfs to mount the remote watch dir locally.